# sklearn and weka kNN predictions exactly same for all except for one data point

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, weka, knn

I wrote a code for kNN using sklearn and then compared the predictions using the WEKA kNN. The comparison was done using the 10 test set predictions, out of which, only a single one is showing a high difference of >1.5 but all others are exactly the same. So, I am not sure about if my code is working fine or not. Here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('xxxx.csv')
X = df.drop(['Name', 'activity'], axis=1)
y = df['activity']
Xstd = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Xstd, y, test_size=0.2, 
shuffle=False, random_state=None)
print(x_train.shape, x_test.shape)
X_train_trans = x_train
X_test_trans = x_test
for i in range(2, 3):
    knn_regressor = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=i, algorithm='brute', 
weights='uniform', metric='euclidean', n_jobs=1, p=2)

    CV_pred_train = cross_val_predict(knn_regressor, X_train_trans, y_train, 
n_jobs=-1, verbose=0, cv=LeaveOneOut())
    print("LOO Q2: ", metrics.r2_score(y_train, CV_pred_train).round(2))
    

    # Train Test predictions
    knn_regressor.fit(X_train_trans, y_train)
    train_r2 = knn_regressor.score(X_train_trans, y_train)
    y_train_pred = knn_regressor.predict(X_train_trans).round(3)
    train_r2_1 = metrics.r2_score(y_train, y_train_pred)
    y_test_pred = knn_regressor.predict(X_test_trans).round(3)
    train_r = stats.pearsonr(y_train, y_train_pred)

    abs_error_train = (y_train - y_train_pred)
    train_predictions = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_train, 'Predcited': 
    y_train_pred, "error": abs_error_train.round(3)})
    MAE_train = metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_train, y_train_pred)

    abs_error_test = (y_test_pred - y_test)
    test_predictions = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'predcited': 
    y_test_pred, 'error': abs_error_test.round(3)})

    test_r = stats.pearsonr(y_test, y_test_pred)
    test_r2 = metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_test_pred)
    MAE_test = metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_test_pred).round(3)
    print(test_predictions)
```

The train set statistics are almost same in both sklearn and WEKA kNN.
the sklearn predictions are:

```
Actual  predcited  error
6.00      5.285 -0.715
5.44      5.135 -0.305
6.92      6.995  0.075
7.28      7.005 -0.275
5.96      6.440  0.480
7.96      7.150 -0.810
7.30      6.660 -0.640
6.68      7.200  0.520
***4.60      6.950  2.350***
```

and the weka predictions are:

```
actual  predicted      error
6          5.285     -0.715 
5.44       5.135     -0.305 
6.92       6.995      0.075 
7.28       7.005     -0.275 
5.96       6.44       0.48  
7.96       7.15      -0.81  
7.3        6.66      -0.64  
6.68       7.2        0.52  
***4.6        5.285      0.685***
```

parameters used in both algorithms are: k =2, brute force for distance calculation, metric: euclidean.

Any suggestions for the difference?

Comment: In skl, you could run the `kneighbors` method to see what the closest two points to the anomalous point were.  It could be that multiple points tie for second-closest, so that the difference is the tie-breaker.

Comment: @BenReiniger Thanks for your suggestion. I did it and there are clear two training data points near to the anomalous point (distance 4.6 and 4.5) and the average value (Y) of these two points is depicted as the test set prediction. I don't know how to get the NNs from weka but surely the NNs considered in the WEKA are different from sklearn (for this anomalous point).

Comment: PS: I tried to compare 4 data sets and in 2 the predictions are identical however, in the 2 datasets the test set predictions vary for 1-2 data points only and are identical for other test set data points.

Comment: It looks like you already ran with 3 neighbors: what's the third distance (to check the hypothesis in my second sentence)?

Comment: indeed I ran with two only, but now i tried with 3 as well and the third distance is 5.10 (distinct from the earlier two and there is no "tie")